# Why am I getting the error local variable 'user_form' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In the code, why am I getting "local variable 'user_form' referenced before assignment" error?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm

def index(request):
 return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):

 registered=False

 if request.method=="POST":
    user_form=UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user=user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password) #Hashing the password
        user.save()

        profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user=user #Sets up one to one relationship

        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered=True

        else:

            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)


    else:
        user_form=UserForm()
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()

return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})
```

This is in the views.py file.
Have been stuck on this project since a while. Please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DJANGO - local variable 'form' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748734/django-local-variable-form-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: I want information related to my code. Hence I have asked again. Please see for the differences and then report.

Comment: Pretty simple: You're referencing the user_form in your render method which is outside the if condition. Thus, referenced before assignments. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your second else block is indented too far. Move it back one level.

Answer (score 0):

You have indenting issue.. Check the edited one here

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')


def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)  # Hashing the password
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user  # Sets up one to one relationship

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
                profile.save()
                registered = True

            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)



    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()
    return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',  {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered})
```